# Flutter app not running on debug mode Pixel6 pro

Tags: android, flutter

I have a problem since yesterday when I upgraded my Pixel Pro 6 to android 13 I can't install apps in debug mode and debug them with the device. 
They get stuck on

```
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
```

I have tried upgrading the compile SDK version to `33` and the Gradle version to `7.2.2` and Kotlin version to `1.7.10` but no luck.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does it also get stuck if trying to install a `.apk` package with command `adb install xxx.apk` in the terminal?

Comment: no it doesn't and that's bad because it does not give any error so I can't debug it

Answer (score 1):

I downgraded my compileSdkVersion to `32` and sadly it solved my issue.

Comment: Thank you for providing the solution, this also helped me. Do you know what the implications are from downgrading from targetSdkVersion 33 to 32?

Comment: @AndreySorokin No in fact I don't know. sorry.